# Update A Column with its same Value in a Table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to update a column with its same value in a table. This is needed because I want to launch the trigger on this table to make some updates in other tables.

Similar to :

Update T1 
Set Col1 = Col1

But this will results in an error.

Thanks

Comment: state the error in the question!

Answer (score 2):

It will result an error only if:

- you have an error in trigger
- there is no table T1 in current database or column Col1 in table T1
- you have the check constraint created `WITH CHECK NOCHECK` and there is datum in the table that violates this constraint
- Update is a following part of error-CTE statement

Comment: Yes, there is an error in the trigger. This query that returns the ID from INSERTED table is returning multiple rows                                                                                         Set @SpecTypeID =  (Select TypeID from  gv_Project_Specs where ID =  (SELECT SpecID FROM INSERTED));

Comment: Why SELECT SpecID FROM INSERTED returns multiple rows ? We live nearby, I am from Lebanon

Comment: Because INSERTED may contain many rows - it contains all rows which is updated or inserted during your UPDATE stmt.

Comment: Maybe downvoted (but not by me) because your list isn't definitive e.g. will result in an error when followed by a statement beginning with the keyword `WITH`.

Comment: @onedaywhen Ah! You right. But I think that list is sufficiently comprehensive.